# How do I combine rules and facts from a PROLOG program into a list?

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof

Im trying to find the list of all release dates of all intel processors. It should look like this

[1993, 1976, 1974, 1971]

Currently I can only create a list with 1 entry like this

`setof(Y,released(pentium,Y),S1)` which gives me [1993].

```
prozessor(i4004).
prozessor(i8080).
prozessor(z80).
prozessor(i8086).
prozessor(a486).
prozessor(pentium).
prozessor(k5).
intel([i4004,i8080,i8086,pentium])
zylog([z80]).
amd([a486,k5]).

released(i4004, 1971).
released(i8080, 1974).
released(z80,1976).
released(i8086,1976).
released(a486,1991).
released(pentium,1993).
released(k5,1996).

influence(i4004,i8080).
influence(i8080,i8086).
influence(i8086,pentium).
influence(i8080,z80).
influence(i8086,a486).
influence(a886,k5).
```

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @WillNess say thank you, of course.

Comment: @TA_intern they should accept the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can collect the set of all Intel processor release years like this:

```
setof(Year, intel_release_year(Year), IntelReleaseYears).
```

For this you must define `intel_release_year/1`. Given your definitions, this could look like this:

```
intel_release_year(Year) :-
    intel(IntelProcessors),
    member(Processor, IntelProcessors),
    released(Processor, Year).
```

Note that facts of the form

```
somepredicate([a, b, c]).
```

are not necessarily the best possible style. It is often better to use separate facts for the individual objects, rather than grouping them in a list:

```
somepredicate(a).
somepredicate(b).
somepredicate(c).
```

In your example this would be:

```
intel(i4004).
intel(i8080).
intel(i8086).
intel(pentium).
```

and then the definition of `intel_release_year/1` doesn't need to use `member/2` anymore:

```
intel_release_year(Year) :-
    intel(IntelProcessor),
    released(IntelProcessor, Year).
```

In either case, you get:

```
?- setof(Year, intel_release_year(Year), IntelReleaseYears).
IntelReleaseYears = [1971, 1974, 1976, 1993].
```

(Knowing some commenters here, I expect that some might insist that I mention that there is another, strictly inferior way of using `setof/3`. So I mentioned it. Do not use `setof/3` in that different, strictly inferior way.)

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot!

Comment: could you perhaps clarify what you mean in the last sentence please?

Comment: (I'm asking because I don't understand and I would like to know).

Comment: I was referring to `setof`'s ad hoc "lambda-like" syntax: Using `A^B^C^(Foo, Bar, Baz)` instead of a separate, properly named, properly testable and reusable auxiliary predicate definition.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. :) (maybe add this into the answer proper?) of course sometimes the "lambda"  is really called for, when it's very simple one-off thing...

Comment: The thing you call "lambda-like syntax" is perfectly fine, especially if you are using the toplevel to query your database. You could of course argue that one should be using findall instead, but sometimes you might want to not bind one of the variables in the goal while still binding the rest. I would avoid such strong language ("strictly inferior" etc) since people might not have enough experience to tell apart opinions from facts.